# Interoperability between regular and single-wire CAN bus

Tags: can, standard

Is it possible to connect a regular CAN transceiver (ISO 11898-1) to a single-wire CAN bus (SAE J2411) in a compatible way? By "compatible" I mean that the whole system should support valid J2411 bus topologies and baud rates.

If so, what is the recommended way of doing so? Specifically, should CANL be left floating, connected to ground, or something else?