# Compatibility and Interoperability Between CAN Standards

Tags: automotive, can, transceiver

I'm intended to design a CAN system for a automotive scan tool. So, I need to comprise the main CAN standars used nowadays. Searching on the web I found the following options:

- ISO 11519-2:1994 – Low-speed CAN transceiver
- SAE J2411:2000 – Single-wire CAN transceiver
- ISO 11898-2:2003 – High-speed CAN transceiver
- ISO 11898-1:2015 - CAN FD transceiver

I know that CAN FD is backward compatible with CAN 2.0, but the phisycal layer of CAN Low-Speed is not, so I need a separeted transceiver to it. My doubt is about Single Wire CAN(SW CAN), Can I use one of the lines of standard ISO 11898-2 (CANH for example) to communicate on a Single Wire CAN bus ?

In the following figure I summarized the idea and the doubt.

[image: CAN illustration]

So, I would like to know, can I use a regular transceiver (Differential CAN lines), but using just one line, to communicate in a Single Wire bus or is mandatory to have a Single Wire CAN transceiver ?

There is similar question, without answer, that were made in the following post:

[Interoperability between regular and single-wire CAN bus](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/409712/interoperability-between-regular-and-single-wire-can-bus)

Comment: Do you actually know that you need to support low-speed and single-wire though, or is that just speculation? They are pretty exotic and not commonly used.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not sure how often it can be useful. But, we have reports of cars that use it. So, I decided to maintain it.

Comment: If you want to support weird old stuff, I would guess that something like J1850 is far more common than low-speed or single-wire, at least for OBD. Haven't used it myself, so I don't know much about it.

Comment: @Lundin yes they are, J1850 and others protocols already are supported.  I'm in doubt about CAN standards

Comment: Maybe it would be OK to poke the car mechanics site about which buses that are commonly used on the market (check at their meta if such questions are on-topic). At any rate you'll probably have to decide a year from which you will start to support existing buses. Supporting everything from 1990 and beyond will be a huge task.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, it is a good idea. Do you know a good mechanic site for reference ?

Comment: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/ but I don't know what's on-topic there. Just like any SE site, I don't imagine that they like too broad questions.